# AWS API Gateway not invoking specified lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, api-gateway, aws-api-gateway

I recently deployed a new API endpoint and linked it to a specified lambda via cloud formation.

```
          x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
            uri: !Join 
              - ''
              - - 'arn:aws:apigateway:'
                - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
                - ':lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:'
                - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
                - ':'
                - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
                - ':function:'
                - !Ref lbdBusinessPersonAccountsFunctionName
                - '-'
                - !Ref EnvName
                - ':live'
                - /invocations
```

When I check the API Gateway console, It seems like the lambda is correctly integrated to the API endpoint. But when I check the lambda console itself, no API GW trigger event was generated.

When I try manually link it to the gateway, it doesn't let me specify the resource I want to link it to, but instead creates a new resource under the lambda name.

Is there a manual linking step that I am missing?

Comment: Can you show full API resource integration definition?

Comment: Did you create a stage and deploy the api?

Answer (score 0):

On your cloudformation template, assuming you are using YAML; add the permissions mapping resource below. This gives apigateway the permission to add trigger/invoke your lambda (this is in addition to the appropriate IAM permissions).

```
FunctionInvokePermissions:
  Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
  Properties:
    Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    FunctionName: !GetAtt "Function.Arn"
    Principal: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
    SourceArn: !Sub 
      - "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${RestApiId}/${pathpart}/${method}"
```